# Как получить конкретный компонент из контейнера Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Я регистрирую в Autofac несколько классов под одним интерфейсом:

```
ContainerBuilder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<MyInterface>();
ContainerBuilder.RegisterType<Class2>().As<MyInterface>();
```

Затем я хочу получить **только** `Class2`, как мне это сделать? Я не хочу использовать перечисление, а затем вычислять конкретный тип из контейнера:

```
//Нежелательный длинный способ
Class2 myClass2 = null;
using(var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
   IEnumerable<MyInterface> items = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<MyInterface>>();
   foreach(var item in items)
      if(item.GetType() == typeof(Class2))
         myClass2 = (Class2)item;
}
```

Comment: Идея DI как раз в том, чтобы не получать конкретную реализацию, похоже вы делаете что-то не то, расскажите вашу задачу подробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно вызывать тип конкретно, при этом не теряя возможность получить коллекцию экземпляров по интерфейсу, то надо изменить регистрацию

```
builder.RegisterType<Class2>().As<MyInterface>().AsSelf();
```

```
Class2 item = scope.Resolve<Class2>();
```